# How to fill JFrame window with a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to set a JPanel fill the whole window of a JFrame. The layout of JPanel is GridBagLayout. If i change it to BorderLayout it works. But i need the GridBagLayout and in this way the JPanel appears on the Center of the window.
How can i fill the whole window of JFrame with the JPanel( just like with BorderLayout )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you read [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Next, make sure you have [the JavaDocs for GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) open and available

These two basic references will provide you with 99% of the information you need to answer just about most of you issues.

Without more context, something like...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

will achieve the result you're looking for

Remember though, you are not stuck to a single layout manager, you can use multiple containers all using different layout managers to achieve your desired results

Comment: Still doesnt work. I have a button on the JPanel that i use GridBagLayout and it appears on the center of the window. I want it to appear on the south side of the window. I used anchor with GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END and then panel.add( btn, gbc ).

Comment: @ThomasAthanasiou Then you are doing something wrong - without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem, it's going to be impossible to know what it is you're doing wrong